# how to use document.getElementById to display the textfield from table using combobox select

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, typescript

i have a combo box which is collecting fields from table and i would like to use the selected id to display other values in different text boxes. get Element By Id only returns a single field.

```
    <?php
    $druglquery = "SELECT ID,DrugName,DrugForm  FROM DrugsInformation ";
    $druglresult = $mysqli->druglquery($druglquery) ; //onchange='submitForm();'
    ?>

    <select style='width:242px;'  id="dcodeID"  onchange="onselectchange();">
    <option value=''></option>
    <?php

    $row = $druglresult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
    printf ("%s (%s)\n", $row[0], $row["DrugName"]);

    ?>

    </select>

    <script> 
    function onselectchange() 
    {
    var d=document.getElementById("dcodeID")
    var diplaytext=d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("test").value=diplaytext;
    alert(" ok ok");
    }


    </script>
```

using the same id i would like to have something like below

```
    <script> 
    function onselectchange() 
    {
    var d=document.getElementById("dcodeID")
    var diplaytext=d.options[d.selectedIndex].text;
    document.getElementById("test").value=diplaytext;
    document.getElementById("test2").value=diplaytext;
    document.getElementById("test3").value=diplaytext;
    alert(" ok ok");
    }


    </script>
```

Comment: Check the source of your site. Your `<select>` will have only one `<option>` and a bunch of unrelated text.

Comment: you asked a very similar question a couple of days ago but then, as now, it is now clear what you are really trying to do. If you were to add the actual code rather than little pieces it might be clearer?! Incidentally a `combobox` is not native to HTML - you refer to  the `select` menu I assume. I think a combobox is used in MS forms

Comment: yes i refer to a sect menu, let me add full code

Comment: `mysqli` does not have a method `druglquery` so `$mysqli->druglquery` is wrong

Comment: its supposed to be mysqli->query and not drugquery sorry for that, should i add to a question as answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking through the modified version of the answer I previously provided I believe you were trying to do something like this. In the previous example I only used a static array so that I could emulate/mimic a typical recordset rather than as the solution itself which, after all, really was the Javascript!

However, in your modified code you assigned values from the recordset to the `$arr` variable but on each iteration through the recordset you simply overwrote the previous values which meant at the end of the loop there would have been a single dimension in the array.

That stage is unnecessary when you are processing the recordset ( remember I only used the array to emulate the recordset ) - iterate through the `$results` and generate the menu directly as before ( for convenience and clarity I like `printf` )

```
<?php

    error_reporting( E_ALL );
    
    $dbhost =   'localhost';
    $dbuser =   'root'; 
    $dbpwd  =   'xxx'; 
    $dbname =   'drugmgmnt';
    
    mysqli_report( MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT );
    $mysqli= new mysqli( $dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpwd, $dbname );
    $mysqli->set_charset('utf8');
    
    $DrugName=filter_input(INPUT_GET,'DrugName',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $DrugForm=filter_input(INPUT_GET,'DrugForm',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $Strength=filter_input(INPUT_GET,'Strength',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $Units=filter_input(INPUT_GET,'Units',FILTER_SANITIZE_STRING);
    $QtyInPack=filter_input(INPUT_GET,'QtyInPack',FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
    
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{
                let oForm=document.forms.admin;
                document.querySelector('select[name="drug"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
                    let option=this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];

                    oForm.Strength.value=option.dataset.strength;
                    oForm.Units.value=option.dataset.units;
                    oForm.DrugForm.value=option.dataset.drugform;
                    oForm.PackType.value=option.dataset.packtype;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='admin' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name='drug'>
                            <option >Please select your drug
                            <?php
                                $sql = "select 
                                    `id`,
                                    `drugname`,
                                    `strength`,
                                    `drugform`,
                                    `units`,
                                    `packtype` 
                                from `drugsinformation`";
                                
                                $result = $mysqli->query( $sql );
                                while( $row = $result->fetch_assoc() ){
                                    printf(
                                        '<option value="%d" data-strength="%d" data-units="%d" data-packtype="%s" data-drugform="%s">%s',
                                        $row['id'],
                                        $row['strength'],
                                        $row['units'],
                                        $row['packtype'],
                                        $row['drugform'],
                                        $row['drugname']
                                    );
                                }
                            }
                            ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Strength: <input type='text' name='Strength' /></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Units: <input type='text' name='Units' /></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>DrugForm: <input type='text' name='DrugForm' /></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>PackType: <input type='text' name='PackType' /></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understood correctly then I hope the following might offer some guidance to help solve the problem you have with your real code.

```
<?php

    # a static array to emulate a basic recordset
    # this is just dummy data

    $drugs=array(
        array('id'=>1,  'name'=>'Abutilon','price'=>'25',       'form'=>'tablet',       'quantity'=>50,     'manufacturer'=>'ACME Drugs Corp' ),
        array('id'=>2,  'name'=>'Pramaxil','price'=>'50',       'form'=>'injection',    'quantity'=>20,     'manufacturer'=>'ACME Cybernautics Division' ),
        array('id'=>3,  'name'=>'Exylichnine','price'=>'150',   'form'=>'suppository',  'quantity'=>30,     'manufacturer'=>'ACME Corporate Greed Division' ),
        array('id'=>4,  'name'=>'BoronHydroxil','price'=>'55',  'form'=>'cream',        'quantity'=>1,      'manufacturer'=>'ACME Famine Feasibility' ),
        array('id'=>5,  'name'=>'Dexaclam','price'=>'10',       'form'=>'tablet',       'quantity'=>100,    'manufacturer'=>'ACME Drugs Corp' )
    );
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang='en'>
    <head>
        <meta charset='utf-8' />
        <script>
            document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{

                let oForm=document.forms.admin;

                document.querySelector('select[name="drugs"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
                    let option=this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];

                    oForm.price.value=option.dataset.price;
                    oForm.quantity.value=option.dataset.quantity;
                    oForm.form.value=option.dataset.form;
                    oForm.manufacturer.value=option.dataset.manufacturer;
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name='admin' method='post'>
            <table>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <select name='drugs'>
                            <option selected hidden disabled>Please select your drug
                            <?php
                                /* emulate iterating through recordset */
                                foreach( $drugs as $arr ){
                                    printf(
                                        '<option value="%d" data-price="%s" data-quantity="%d" data-manufacturer="%s" data-form="%s">%s', 
                                        $arr['id'],
                                        $arr['price'],
                                        $arr['quantity'],
                                        $arr['manufacturer'],
                                        $arr['form'],
                                        $arr['name']
                                    );
                                }
                            ?>
                        </select>                   
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Price: <input type='text' name='price' /></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Quantity: <input type='text' name='quantity' /></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Form: <input type='text' name='form' /></label>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <label>Manufacturer: <input type='text' name='manufacturer' /></label>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{

  let oForm=document.forms.admin;

  document.querySelector('select[name="drugs"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
    let option=this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];

    oForm.price.value=option.dataset.price;
    oForm.quantity.value=option.dataset.quantity;
    oForm.form.value=option.dataset.form;
    oForm.manufacturer.value=option.dataset.manufacturer;
  });
});
```

```html
<form name='admin' method='post'>
  <table>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <select name='drugs'>
          <option selected hidden disabled>Please select your drug
          <option value="1" data-price="25" data-quantity="50" data-manufacturer="ACME Drugs Corp" data-form="tablet">Abutilon
          <option value="2" data-price="50" data-quantity="20" data-manufacturer="ACME Cybernautics Division" data-form="injection">Pramaxil
          <option value="3" data-price="150" data-quantity="30" data-manufacturer="ACME Corporate Greed Division" data-form="suppository">Exylichnine
          <option value="4" data-price="55" data-quantity="1" data-manufacturer="ACME Famine Feasibility" data-form="cream">BoronHydroxil
          <option value="5" data-price="10" data-quantity="100" data-manufacturer="ACME Drugs Corp" data-form="tablet">Dexaclam
        </select>     
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Price: <input type='text' name='price' /></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Quantity: <input type='text' name='quantity' /></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Form: <input type='text' name='form' /></label>
      </td>
      <td>
        <label>Manufacturer: <input type='text' name='manufacturer' /></label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
   <form id="customForm" method="get" action="" >   

   <?php
   require_once('../connection/config.php');    
   ?>

   <td width="" valign="top"><span class="mandatory">*</span> Drug Name <br>
                    <div><?php 
                    if ($SavedDrug !="")
    {       
    $DLNames=Getdrugname($SavedDrug);
    ?>
    <div class="notice">
    <?php 
    echo '<strong>'.$DLNamed.'</strong>';
    echo"<input name='dcode' type='hidden' value='$SavedDrug' />";?>
    </div>
    <?php
    }
        else
        {   ?>  
              <?php
     $druglquery = "SELECT ID,DrugName,DrugForm  FROM DrugsInformation ";
       $druglresult = $mysqli->query($druglquery) ; //onchange='submitForm();'
     ?>

     </div>
      <select style='width:242px;'  id="dcodeID"  onchange="onselectchange();">
      <option value=''></option>
          <?php

          $row = $druglresult->fetch_array(MYSQLI_BOTH);
     {       $dID = $row['ID'];
        $dname = $row['DrugName'];
        $dform = $row['DrugForm'];
          ?>

     <option value="<?php echo  $dID; ?>"><?php echo $dname; ?><?php echo $dform; ?> 
  </option>

        <?php
        }?>
        </select><span id="dcode"></span>


              <?php
         }
    ?>
    </td>            

    <td > Drug Form <br>
            <input type="text" name="$DrugForm " id="$DrugForm " class="text" 
    size="25" value="" /><br> <span id="msgbox1"></span><span id="msgbox" 
    style="display:none" 
    ></span></td>

    <td > Quantity in Pack <br>
    <input type="text" name="$qty " id="$qty " class="text" size="25" value="" /><br> 
    <span id="msgbox3"></span><span id="msgbox2" style="display:none" ></span></td>             

      </form>
```

Comment: There are some basic errors with your HTML markup but how bad these are is not clear because you have only added portions of your code. In essence you CANNOT start a `table`, and then have a `form` like you have above. A form can be wholly within a single `TD` or the entire table can be within the `form` - you cannot straddle elements as you do here. Without seeing all the code it is very hard to really help. You wish to use the `change` event handler on the `select` menu to populate various fields with information but you fail to identify which fields.

Comment: `name="$DrugForm "` will display, in the textfield, a value of `"$DrugForm "` as the name rather than the value of that variable as you have not echoed it. Also - the trailing space WILL become part of the name so might break later processing as that field will be incorrectly named. The same is true for `name="$qty "`

Comment: A table within a form, i do not want to bring a very complicated explanation thats why i only chose a few code lines, previously what i brought did not make sense at all, so i wanted to simplify my question. basically the function is only calling drug name and its output is a text test, but what i want is that when i call drug name i have to call other fields like drugform and assign in other different text

Comment: you cannot have a form inside a form

Comment: sorry typo a table is within a form

Comment: how best can i use this code to separate two values, for example when i call for the drug name panadol, i should be able to see drugform and qty in different text using   var d=document.getElementById("dcodeID")

Comment: do you wish to populate other fields with data when the SELECT changes OR combine the values from other form elements into your javascript function? It is not clear

Comment: yes i wish to to populate other fields on the same selected value/name

Comment: did you look at the example I posted above? Does that do something like what you are trying to do (because I'm still not 100% certain of what you are trying to explain )

Comment: if that helped perhaps you should accept that answer

Comment: hello Professor am having some minor difficulties with array values from table to populate into combo have a look at the code

Comment: Can you describe what the problems are please?

Comment: @ Professor Abronsius any assistance ?

Comment: what exactly is the problem - I can't really deduce the problem by looking at lots of code

Comment: i have two problems, when i use subarray to below variables i get undefined 
        'ID' and the above foreach loops only the last record

Comment: second error /* when i use ($d['ID']) i get this 
        error on all be variables Illegal string offset 'ID*/

Comment: which piece of code should one look at? The updated version based upon the answer I gave previously or the badly formatted code immediately above here?

Comment: Marvelous  Professor Abronsius  thanks a lot !! have a beautiful day !!!!

Comment: Hello Professor Abronsius, thanks a lot for the support you offered a year ago, i would like to you the same technic of populating option values but now it has to be outside the form and inside form class

Comment: @ProfessorAbronsiusa any suggestion

Comment: There should be no significant difference between populating outside a form or within a form class. What is the problem?

Comment: am using a bootstrap to get data and the function is not working on bootstrap, am thinking maybe am populating outside the form, i even created a new ticket on the same subject https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69750693/how-to-display-table-values-in-an-input-box-using-dropdown-option

Answer (score 0):

```
based on the solution you provided i was able to recreate the code and unfortunately i have problems on when i use the combo. i only get last record from the table looped a number of records in the table, i have 5 test records and its looping the last record 4 times. from loop foreach statement all subarray variable used are bring errors as indicated on the code below is output of array generating code 

  Array ( [ID] => 6 [DrugName] => mm [Strength] => 30 [DrugForm] => ML [Units] => mg 
 [PackType] => Bx ) Array ( [ID] => 7 [DrugName] => test [Strength] => 30 [DrugForm] 
  => Box [Units] => mg [PackType] => Bx ) Array ( [ID] => 8 [DrugName] => test2 
  [Strength] => 12 [DrugForm] => ML [Units] => g [PackType] => Bt ) Array ( [ID] => 9 
  [DrugName] => test3 [Strength] => 54 [DrugForm] => ML [Units] => mg [PackType] => Bx 
  ) Array ( [ID] => 10 [DrugName] => test4 [Strength] => 54 [DrugForm] => ML [Units] 
   => mg [PackType] => Bx ) Array ( [ID] => 11 [DrugName] => test5 [Strength] => 455 
 [DrugForm] => Aerosol [Units] => mg [PackType] => Bx )







<?php


       session_start();
    // produce array

    $mysqli = new mysqli("localhost", "root", "", "drugmgmnt");

    /* check connection */
    if ($mysqli->connect_errno) {
      printf("Connect failed: %s\n", $mysqli->connect_error);
      exit();
    }



         if(isset($_GET['DrugName'])){
           $DrugName = $_GET['DrugName']; 
          }else{
        $DrugName = "";
   }

    if(isset($_GET['DrugForm '])){
  $DrugForm  = $_GET['DrugForm ']; 
   }else{
  $DrugForm  = "";
   }

     if(isset($_GET['Strength '])){
     $Strength  = $_GET['Strength ']; 
     }else{
    $Strength  = "";
    }

    if(isset($_GET['Units '])){
    $Units  = $_GET['Units ']; 
   }else{
    $Units  = "";
    }

    if(isset($_GET['QtyInPack '])){
    $QtyInPack  = $_GET['QtyInPack ']; 
    }else{
   $QtyInPack  = "";
    }


   if(isset($_GET['ID '])){
   $ID  = $_GET['ID ']; 
   }else{
   $ID  = "";
   }





   $druglquery = "SELECT ID,DrugName,Strength,DrugForm,Units,PackType  FROM DrugsInformation ";
  
   if  ($result = $mysqli->query($druglquery))

    
       $arr = Array();
 
    while ($row = $result ->fetch_assoc())
    {
    $arr['ID'] = $row['ID'];
    $arr['DrugName'] = $row['DrugName'];
    $arr['Strength'] = $row['Strength'];
    $arr['DrugForm'] = $row['DrugForm'];
    $arr['Units'] = $row['Units'];
    $arr['PackType'] = $row['PackType'];
    print_r($arr);  /* i used this to view the array generated above*/

    }



   ?>
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang='en'>
   <head>
    <meta charset='utf-8' />
    <script>
        document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{

            let oForm=document.forms.admin;

            
   document.querySelector('select[name="drug"]').addEventListener('change',function(e) 
        {
                let option=this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];

                oForm.Strength.value=option.dataset.Strength;
                oForm.Units.value=option.dataset.Units;
                oForm.DrugForm.value=option.dataset.DrugForm;
                oForm.PackType.value=option.dataset.PackType;
            });
        });
        </script>
       </head>
    <body>
       <form name='admin' method='post'>
        <table>
            <tr>
                <td>
                    <select name='drug'>
                        <option >Please select your drug
                        <?php
                            /* emulate iterating through recordset */
                            
                            
                            foreach( $arr as $d ){
                        //  when i use subarray to below variables i get undefined 
        'ID' and the above foreach loops only the last record 
                           printf(
                                  '<option value="%d" data-Strength="%d" data- 
        Units="%d" data-PackType="%s" data-DrugForm="%s">%s', 
                                   $arr['ID'], /* when i use ($d['ID']) i get this 
        error on all be variables Illegal string offset 'ID*/
                                  $arr['Strength'],
                                   $arr['Units'],
                                   $arr['PackType'],
                                   $arr['DrugForm'],
                                  $arr['DrugName']
                               );
                           }
                        ?>
                    </select>                   
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Strength: <input type='text' name='Strength' /></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>Units: <input type='text' name='Units' /></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>DrugForm: <input type='text' name='DrugForm' /></label>
                </td>
                <td>
                    <label>PackType: <input type='text' name='PackType' /></label>
                </td>
            </tr>
        </table>
       </form>
       </body>
     </html>
```