# how to display table values in an input box using dropdown option

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

```js
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded',e=>{

  let oForm=document.forms.admin;

  document.querySelector('select[name="drugs"]').addEventListener('change',function(e){
    let option=this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];

    oForm.price.value=option.dataset.price;
    oForm.quantity.value=option.dataset.quantity;
    oForm.form.value=option.dataset.form;
    oForm.manufacturer.value=option.dataset.manufacturer;
  });
});
```

```html
<body>  
        <div class="container">
            <br />
            
            <h3 align="center">Multiple drug prescription</a></h3><br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div align="right" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <form method="post" id="user_form">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="user_data">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Drug Name</th>
                            <th>Drug Unit</th>
                            <th>Morning</th>
                            <th>Day</th>
                            <th>evening</th>
                            <th>bedtime</th>
                            <th>Duration in days</th>
                            <th>Prescribed</th>
                            <th>Qty in stock</th>
                        
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert" />
                </div>
            </form>

            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="user_dialog" title="Add prescriprion">
        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Drug Name</label>
                <select  name='drugselect 'class="form-control" id="drugselect">
                 <option selected hidden disabled>Please select your drug
          <option value="1" data-unit="mg" data-quantity="50"  data-form="tablet">Abutilon
          <option value="2" data-unit="mg" data-quantity="20"  data-form="injection">Pramaxil
          <option value="3" data-unit="ml" data-quantity="30"  data-form="suppository">Exylichnine
          <option value="4" data-unit="mg" data-quantity="1"  data-form="cream">BoronHydroxil
          <option value="5" data-unit="mg" data-quantity="100"  data-form="tablet">Dexaclam
        
                            
                            ?>
                        </select>
                <span id="error_drgdn" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Drug Unit</label>
                <input type="text" name="Drugunit" id="Drugunit" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgu" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Drug Form</label>
                <input type="text" name="Drugfm" id="Drugfm" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgu" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Morn</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgmorn" id="drgmorn" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgmrn" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Day</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgday" id="drgday" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgd" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>even</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgeve" id="drgeve" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drge" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>bedtime</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgbdt" id="drgbdt" size ="5" class="form-control"  />
                <span id="error_drgbt" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>days</label>
                <input type="text" size ="5" name="drgpdays" id="drgpdays" class="form-control"   />
                <span id="error_drgdys" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>prescribe</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgpriscript" id="drgpriscript" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgpre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>in stock</label>
                <input type="text" name="drginstock" id="drginstock" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgqis" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                <input type="hidden" name="row_id" id="hidden_row_id" />
                <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
            </div>
    
        <div id="action_alert" title="Action">

        </div>
        

    </div>
    </body>
```

I am looking for a a solution of populating table values into multiple input text on a bootstrap window the input text are outside the form and are in a class 'form-group'.

Wwhat I want is that when I select option value certain values from a table on the same id must also display on other textbox inside class `form-group`. the function I have displayed only work when the input text are inside the form.

```html
<html>  
    <head>  
        
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
        <link rel="stylesheet" href="bootstrap.min.css" />
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.js"></script>
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
    </head>  
    <body>  
        <div class="container">
            <br />
            
            <h3 align="center">Multiple drug prescription</a></h3><br />
            <br />
            <br />
            <div align="right" style="margin-bottom:5px;">
                <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success btn-xs">Add</button>
            </div>
            <br />
            <form method="post" id="user_form">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table class="table table-striped table-bordered" id="user_data">
                        <tr>
                            <th>Drug Name</th>
                            <th>Drug Unit</th>
                            <th>Morning</th>
                            <th>Day</th>
                            <th>evening</th>
                            <th>bedtime</th>
                            <th>Duration in days</th>
                            <th>Prescribed</th>
                            <th>Qty in stock</th>
                        
                        </tr>
                    </table>
                </div>
                <div align="center">
                    <input type="submit" name="insert" id="insert" class="btn btn-primary" value="Insert" />
                </div>
            </form>

            <br />
        </div>
        <div id="user_dialog" title="Add prescriprion">
        
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Drug Name</label>
                <select  name='drugselect 'class="form-control" id="drugselect">
                <option >Please select your drug
                            <?php
                                $sqlx = mysqli_query($con,"select 
                                     `drugID`,
                                    `d`.`drugName` as `dname` ,
                                    `catName` as cname,
                                    `drugCategory` as dcat,
                                    `units` as dunits,
                                    `stockqty`
                                     
                                from `drug` `d` JOIN `category` `c` on `d`.`drugCategory` = `c`.`catID` JOIN `pharmacy` `p` on `d`.`drugID` = `p`.`drug` WHERE  `p`.`stockqty` >0 ");
                        

                                while ($rowx=mysqli_fetch_array($sqlx)){
                                
                                
                              
                                    printf(
                                        '<option value="%d"   data-cname="%s" data-stockqty="%d"  data-dcat="%d" data-dunits="%s"  data-dname="%s">%s',
                                        $rowx['drugID'],
                                        $rowx['cname'],
                                        $rowx['stockqty'],
                                        $rowx['dcat'],
                                        $rowx['dunits'],
                                        $rowx['dname'],
                                        $rowx['dname']
                                    );
                                    
                                    
                                }
                            //}
                            
                            
                            ?>
                        </select>
                <span id="error_drgdn" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Drug Unit</label>
                <input type="text" name="Drugunit" id="Drugunit" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgu" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Drug Form</label>
                <input type="text" name="Drugfm" id="Drugfm" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgu" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Morn</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgmorn" id="drgmorn" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgmrn" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>Day</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgday" id="drgday" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgd" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>even</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgeve" id="drgeve" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drge" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>bedtime</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgbdt" id="drgbdt" size ="5" class="form-control"  />
                <span id="error_drgbt" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>days</label>
                <input type="text" size ="5" name="drgpdays" id="drgpdays" class="form-control"   />
                <span id="error_drgdys" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>prescribe</label>
                <input type="text" name="drgpriscript" id="drgpriscript" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgpre" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label>in stock</label>
                <input type="text" name="drginstock" id="drginstock" class="form-control" />
                <span id="error_drgqis" class="text-danger"></span>
            </div>
            <div class="form-group" align="center">
                <input type="hidden" name="row_id" id="hidden_row_id" />
                <button type="button" name="save" id="save" class="btn btn-info">Save</button>
            </div>
    
        <div id="action_alert" title="Action">

        </div>
        

    </div>
    </body>
```

Function below works when `input` box are in a form but I want below functionality to happen on a Bootstrap window.

```html
<script>
    document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', e => {
        let oForm = document.forms.admin;

        document.querySelector('select[name="drugselect"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
            let option = this.options[this.options.selectedIndex];

            oForm.Instock.value = option.dataset.stockqty;
            oForm.catgname.value = option.dataset.cname;
            oForm.drugCategory.value = option.dataset.dcat;
            oForm.Drugunit.value = option.dataset.dunits;
            oForm.DrugName.value = option.dataset.dname;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Please help me with a solution.

Comment: Thanks Alexis Phillip any suggestion?

Comment: The javascript code references a form called `admin` yet the HTML does not name any forms

Answer (score 1):

If I have understood correctly the intention is to populate the `input` elements below the `select` menu when the user changes the selection in that `select` menu. The first piece of HTML above features the dummy data and Javascript I used when answering the [original question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62468269/how-to-use-document-getelementbyid-to-display-the-textfield-from-table-using-com) so I have expanded upon the array data I used then to create the following.

The PHP data to build the menus was used in the same way as in previous answer and yields a select menu as seen below in the snippet.

I must admit that I made a few assumptions as it was not entirely clear what the real problem was/is. For instance - I assumed that the database query should return far more information than shown in your code - afterall why have `input` elements named as they are otherwise if these are not to be the fields that are populated?!

```
$drugs=array(
    array(
        'unit'=>'kg',
        'morning'=>2,
        'day'=>2,
        'evening'=>2,
        'bedtime'=>2,
        'prescriber'=>'Dr. Bob',
        'days'=>14,
        'id'=>1,
        'name'=>'Abutilon',
        'price'=>'25',
        'form'=>'tablet',
        'quantity'=>50,
        'manufacturer'=>'ACME Drugs Corp'
    ),
    array(
        'unit'=>'mg',
        'morning'=>4,
        'day'=>4,
        'evening'=>4,
        'bedtime'=>2,
        'prescriber'=>'Dr. John',
        'days'=>365,
        'id'=>2,
        'name'=>'Pramaxil',
        'price'=>'50',
        'form'=>'injection',
        'quantity'=>20,
        'manufacturer'=>'ACME Cybernautics Division'
    ),
    array(
        'unit'=>'lb',
        'morning'=>1,
        'day'=>1,
        'evening'=>1,
        'bedtime'=>1,
        'prescriber'=>'Dr. Radish',
        'days'=>28,
        'id'=>3,
        'name'=>'Exylichnine',
        'price'=>'150',
        'form'=>'suppository',
        'quantity'=>30,
        'manufacturer'=>'ACME Corporate Greed Division'
    ),
    array(
        'unit'=>'kg',
        'morning'=>6,
        'day'=>2,
        'evening'=>9,
        'bedtime'=>2,
        'prescriber'=>'Dr. Womble',
        'days'=>7,
        'id'=>4,
        'name'=>'BoronHydroxil',
        'price'=>'55',
        'form'=>'cream',
        'quantity'=>1,
        'manufacturer'=>'ACME Famine Feasibility'
    ),
    array(
        'unit'=>'ton',
        'morning'=>2,
        'day'=>2,
        'evening'=>2,
        'bedtime'=>2,
        'prescriber'=>'Dr. Saskia',
        'days'=>30,
        'id'=>5,
        'name'=>'Dexaclam',
        'price'=>'10',
        'form'=>'tablet',
        'quantity'=>100,
        'manufacturer'=>'ACME Drugs Corp'
    )
);
```

```js
const q=(e,n=document)=>n.querySelector(e);


q('select[name="drugselect"]').addEventListener('change', function(e) {
  let option = this.options[ this.options.selectedIndex ];
  for( let attr in option.dataset ){
    let input=q('.form-group input[data-name="'+attr+'"]');
    if( input )input.value=option.dataset[attr];
  }
});
```

```html
<div id='user_dialog' title='Add prescriprion'> 
    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Drug Name</label>

        <select name='drugselect' class='form-control'>
          <option selected hidden disabled>Please select your drug
          <option 
            value="1" 
            data-price="25" 
            data-quantity="50" 
            data-manufacturer="ACME Drugs Corp" 
            data-form="tablet"
            data-unit="kg"
            data-morning="2"
            data-day="2"
            data-evening="2"
            data-bedtime="2"
            data-prescriber="Dr. Bob"
            data-days="14"
          >Abutilon
          
          <option 
            value="2" 
            data-price="50" 
            data-quantity="20" 
            data-manufacturer="ACME Cybernautics Division" 
            data-form="injection"
            data-unit="mg"
            data-morning="4"
            data-day="4"
            data-evening="4"
            data-bedtime="2"
            data-prescriber="Dr. John"
            data-days="365"
          >Pramaxil
          
          <option 
            value="3" 
            data-price="150" 
            data-quantity="30" 
            data-manufacturer="ACME Corporate Greed Division" 
            data-form="suppository"
            data-unit="lb"
            data-morning="1"
            data-day="1"
            data-evening="1"
            data-bedtime="1"
            data-prescriber="Dr. Radish"
            data-days="28"
          >Exylichnine
          
          <option 
            value="4" 
            data-price="55" 
            data-quantity="1" 
            data-manufacturer="ACME Famine Feasibility" 
            data-form="cream"
            data-unit="kg"
            data-morning="6"
            data-day="2"
            data-evening="9"
            data-bedtime="2"
            data-prescriber="Dr. Womble"
            data-days="7"
          >BoronHydroxil
          
          <option 
            value="5" 
            data-price="10" 
            data-quantity="100" 
            data-manufacturer="ACME Drugs Corp" 
            data-form="tablet"
            data-unit="ton"
            data-morning="2"
            data-day="2"
            data-evening="2"
            data-bedtime="2"
            data-prescriber="Dr. Saskia"
            data-days="30"
          >Dexaclam
        </select>
        <span id='error_drgdn' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Drug Unit</label>
        <input type='text' name='Drugunit' class='form-control' data-name='unit' />
        <span id='error_drgu' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Drug Form</label>
        <input type='text' name='Drugfm' class='form-control' data-name='form' />
        <span id='error_drgu' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Morn</label>
        <input type='text' name='drgmorn' class='form-control' data-name='morning' />
        <span id='error_drgmrn' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>Day</label>
        <input type='text' name='drgday' class='form-control' data-name='day' />
        <span id='error_drgd' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>even</label>
        <input type='text' name='drgeve' class='form-control' data-name='evening' />
        <span id='error_drge' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>bedtime</label>
        <input type='text' name='drgbdt' size ='5' class='form-control' data-name='bedtime' />
        <span id='error_drgbt' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>days</label>
        <input type='text' size='5' name='drgpdays' class='form-control' data-name='days' />
        <span id='error_drgdys' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>prescribe</label>
        <input type='text' name='drgpriscript' class='form-control' data-name='prescriber' />
        <span id='error_drgpre' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group'>
        <label>in stock</label>
        <input type='text' name='drginstock' class='form-control' data-name='quantity' />
        <span id='error_drgqis' class='text-danger'></span>
    </div>

    <div class='form-group' align='center'>
        <input type='hidden' name='row_id' />
        <button type='button' name='save' id='save' class='btn btn-info'>Save</button>
    </div>

  <div id='action_alert'></div>
</div>
```

To link the input elements to the `option` selected in the `drugselect` menu I used a `data-name` attribute that is the same as the key in the array. This would be the same as using the `column` name in the sql query. Perhaps, if this is incorrect, you might add the database schema and sample data?

Comment: Thanks @Professor Abronsius let me add database schema, i will let you know asap

Comment: it has worked like magic thanks a lot the genius!!!! much appreciation